# NSClient CheckEventLog gives no entries for id

Tags: networking, monitoring

We have a Red Hat server that runs Icinga2 with NSClient++ 0.5.0.62 to monitor some devices and services in our network. Everything works perfectly fine except for one new check I'm trying to use.

I have to check the event log on one of our servers for the id '208' via Check_NSCP's check CheckEventLog. But when I search for that id I'm not getting any entries even though there are some events with that id.
The command I'm using looks like this:

```
[root@lad-icinga ~]# check_nrpe -H server.domain.ch --certificate /etc/icinga2/pki/server.pem -c CheckEventLog -a file=Application "filter=id='208'"
```

The output of that command looks like this:

```
OK: No entries found|'problem_count'=0;0;0
```

When I look into the event log on that server I see multiple events with the id '208' with the following specifications.

[image: Specifications for event 208]

However, when I try another id, for example '9003', it works. I've also tried it with some other ids and most of them worked.

```
[root@lad-icinga ~]# check_nrpe -H clsrv22.laederachnet.ch --certificate /etc/icinga2/pki/server.pem -c CheckEventLog -a file=Application "filter=id='9003'"
```

Output:

```
Desktop Window Manager, Der Desktopfenster-Manager konnte nicht gestartet werden, da kein zusammengestelltes Design verwendet wird., Desktop Window Manager, Der Desktopfenster-Manager konnte nicht gestartet werden, da kein zusammengestelltes Design verwendet wird., Desktop Window Manager, Der Desktopfenster-Manager konnte nicht gestartet werden, da kein zusammengestelltes Design verwendet wird.
```

As you can see, it finds the id and shows me the message of the id.

The event '9003' looks like this:

[image: Specifications for event 9003]

Like I said I've tried many different ids and most of them did work, however I can't get this one to work.

Can anyone of you help me with this problem?

Thanks